# IBM Rational Integration Tester starter edition won't open project

Tags: integration, ibm-rational

I currently use RIT starter edition on Mac (simply because the licensed version does not work on Mac). I have been using this edition for most of this year.

Today, I was looking for the Linux version to install for a demo, and I noticed that the Mac version was more recent than the one I had installed so I downloaded both.

When I installed this latest release, I could no longer open the project which I have been working with for at least 6 months. The error said that the project was not compatible with the starter edition.

This makes no sense as I had literally opened the same project earlier in the day and worked with it for a presentation.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: You should try searching, checking the chatroom once you have a few more reputation, or posting in a more relevant forum, such as SuperUser. StackOverflow is specifically for code problems :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this.

1. Create a new project with the starter edition, give it the same name, and then close it
2. Copy everything from the existing project, except for the .ghp file
3. Reopent the new project